# Can Windows 10 notifications be forwarded to another computer?

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I have a home server running Windows 10 Pro. Since there isn't an active monitor attached to it most of the time, I don't tend to find out about any notifications until I remote desktop to it for another reason (e.g. I didn't see the Anniversary Edition upgrade notification for a few months after it was available - well after I'd forgotten it had already been applied to my other computers).

Is there a way to forward any notifications generated (such as updates ready to install) to another computer?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work [Growl for Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/)

[image]

Comment: I *very* much doubt this would forward Windows 10 notifications.